# Red5 with OpenCv - What do you think?

Tags: opencv, red5, rtsp, rtmp

I have a opencv application tracking head from webcam.
I like to have something which will transfer live video stream of webcam to server where opencv program is running.
Opencv program manipulating image and transferring it to web-browser.
I have looked at

**1. Red5 -** (http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/Install)
**2. jquery Webcam -** (http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/)
**3. nimbb -** (http://nimbb.com/Help/Api.aspx)
**4. crtmpserver -** (http://rtmpd.org) as @ciphor suggested

```
1 Red5 - I was getting build error when I am trying to install.(Now its working fine)
2 jquery Webcam - Is very slow I can't think of getting a video stream.(I don't want to use this)
3 nimbb - Is paid service so I have not looked at it.
4 crtmpserver - As Red5 worked I am no more interested
```

Please give me an idea which one to use.
If you thing Red5 is best give me tutorial to install (only if you have successfully installed it)

Please Help.

Comment: I didnt got the answer....
Please Help !!!!

Comment: I saw your msg on Gstreamer-devel :)

Comment: Ya thats me...I am very curious to know...

Comment: @karlphillip Can you please tell me....That is do-able....

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never used any of these tools and I find the challenge quite interesting (that's why I upvoted it). I would probably end up writing my own solution. Best of luck!

Comment: @karlphillip - You found it interesting feels good....Please help me out if you get the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is crtmpserver - (http://www.rtmpd.com/ )
The installation is quite easy on Linux systems, using cmake.
This software supports RTMP, RTSP, MPEG-TS protocols.

Comment: +1 Have you tried that...This is something new I got other than red5 are you very much sure about it...Thanks for the reply...

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. It's a cool software, good architecture and much better performance than red5.

Comment: I didnt got the correct answer ciphor....Though you have attempted It so I thought why not giving you +50

Comment: Could you tell me what problem you've met?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem exactly. You have installed Red5 successfully, right? Could you obtain live video stream from Red5 now?

Comment: ya...I can...What I am using in between client and server is Opencv program to manipulate the output...But unable to stream it from OpenCv program...Will you please help me out....

Comment: The OpenCv program get video stream from Red5, but unable to stream it to client?